# Derivative of $e^{-x} - xe^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

Find $f'(x)$:

$$f(x) = e^{-x} - xe^{-x}$$
$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}-(x)'(e^{-x})+(x)(e^{-x})'$$
$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}-e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$$
$$f'(x) = -2e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$$
$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}(2+x)$$

However the answer states:
$$f'(x) = e^{-x}(x-2)$$

I am not sure where I made a mistake.

Comment: In the second line, your + should be -.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}-(x)'(e^{-x})+(x)(e^{-x})'$$

Should be

$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}-[(x)'(e^{-x})+(x)(e^{-x})']$$
$$f'(x) = -e^{-x}-(x)'(e^{-x})-(x)(e^{-x})'$$

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses:

$$f\,'(x)=-e^{-x}-\left(x'e^{-x}+x(e^{-x})'\right)=-e^{-x}-e^{-x}+xe^{-x}=(x-2)e^{-x}\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

between the 2nd and the 3rd line, you have 2 minuses in the $f * g'$ - one from the line before and one from the derivative of $e^{-x}$ so it should be +$xe^{-x}$ in the 3rd line

Answer (score 1):

The mistake occurs on the second line.  It should read:

$$f'(x) = -e^{-x} -((x)'e^{-x} + x(e^{-x})'),$$

since you are subtracting the whole derivative $(xe^{-x})'$.

Answer (score 1):

On the second line your "+" should be a "-".  Try pulling a -1 out of the $-xe^{-x}$ term before using the product rule.